# Fonts added to the TinyMCE are not apply style

Tags: tinymce

I want to add new fonts to tinymce . I put my fonts in tiff format in the following path:
tinymce/themes/advanced/fonts/

In the two files editor_template.js and editor_template_src.js, in the theme_advanced_fonts section, I added the fonts name as follows:
theme_advanced_fonts : "B Nazanin=BNazanin,B Titr=BTitrBd;Andale Mono=andale mono,times;Arial=arial...

It is now displayed in the font dropdown editor, but when I select that font for an example: B Titr, the font of that expression will not be change to B Titr.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Are you passing CSS to the editor that includes these fonts?  The editor itself is an iFrame so you need to pass CSS to the editor that includes these fonts so that when you try to use them the browser knows how to render them.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css